# Angular return httpclient response that object with sub object [object object]

Tags: angular, httpclient

[image: This is output]

[image: This is response read in]cmCm.png

```
export class HttTestComponent implements OnInit {


  student:User;
  grade:Grade;

  constructor(private service:HttTestserviceService) { }

 


  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getStudentDetails().subscribe(response=>this.student=response);
  }

}
```

```
export class HttTestserviceService {

  private usersUrl: string;
 
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.usersUrl = 'http://localhost:....';
  }

 
  getStudentDetails() : Observable<User>{
    return this.http.get<User>(this.usersUrl+"/getStudentDetails/");
  }
```

```
import  {Grade} from "../app/grade"

export interface User {
    studentId: string;
    studentName: string;
    dob: string;
    listGrade:Grade;
}
```

```
export interface Grade {
    gradeId:string;
    gradeName:string;
    gradePoint:number;
}
```

Just leaning angular for a few days. I was not able to get listGrade of the object to display properly. As shown in the image I got [object object]. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: What does your html look like? What exactly do you want it to output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you just bound all `student` properties into view and `listGrade` prop is a list of objects type and angular doesn't know how to display it. Just try `@ngFor` directive like this:

```
<div>{{ student.studentId }}</div>
<div>{{ student.studentName }}</div>
<div>{{ student.dob }}</div>
<div *ngFor="let grade of listGrade">
    <div>{{ grade.gradeID }}</div>
    <div>{{ grade.gradeName }}</div>
    <div>{{ grade.gradePoint }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

@learnisgood, listGrade is an Array -in the e.g. you put with an unique element- I don't know if your error is that in the interface need write

export interface User {
studentId: string;
studentName: string;
dob: string;
listGrade:Grade[]; //<--indicate that is an array
}
If is an array you need use a *ngFor to show it, e.g.

```
<div *ngFor="let grade of student.listGrade">
{{grade.gradeName}}
</div>
```

Or if you're sure that always receive an array with an unique element you can use some like

```
  subscribe(response=>this.student=
     {...response,
      listGrade:response.listGrade[0]
      })
```

NOTE: I use the spreadOperator to make a copy of the object

NOTE2: sometime is util in the .html write for check

```
<pre>
{{student|json}}
</pre>
```

Comment: instead of *ngfor, can I written like this  ```<div>{{ student.studentId }}</div>
  <div>{{ student.studentName }}</div>
  <div>{{ student.dob }}</div>
      <div>{{ grade.gradeID }}</div>
      <div>{{ grade.gradeName }}</div>
      <div>{{ grade.gradePoint }}</div>
```

Comment: If listGrade is an array you need write `{{listGrade[0].gradeName}}`